# String Concatenation through Operator overloading

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class, char

**QUESTION**

*Write a C++ program to overload '+' operator to concatenate two strings.*

This program is done on my OOP book of Robert Lafore fourth edition Object Oriented programming but seems to not be able to convert char to string. The program is well written and fulfills the requirement but the one error it gives makes it hard to understand. I cant seem to find the problem in it.

error it gives is that character cannot be converted to string.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;#include <string.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

class String //user-defined string type
{
    private:
        enum {
            SZ = 80
        }; //size of String objects
    char str[SZ]; //holds a string

    public:
        String() //constructor, no args
    {
        strcpy(str, "");
    }
    String(char s[]) //constructor, one arg
    {
        strcpy(str, s);
    }
    void display() const //display the String
    {
        cout << str;
    }
    String operator + (String ss) const //add Strings
    {
        String temp;

        if (strlen(str) + strlen(ss.str) < SZ) {
            strcpy(temp.str, str); //copy this string to temp
            strcat(temp.str, ss.str); //add the argument string
        } else {
            cout << “\nString overflow”;
            exit(1);
        }
        return temp; //return temp String
    }
};

////////////////////////////////MAIN////////////////////////////////

int main() {
    String s1 = “\nMerry Christmas!“; //uses constructor 2
    String s2 = “Happy new year!”; //uses constructor 2
    String s3; //uses constructor 1

    s1.display(); //display strings
    s2.display();
    s3.display();

    s3 = s1 + s2; //add s2 to s1,

    //assign to s3
    s3.display();
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Heads up: your `“`/`”` double quotes are NOT ascii double quotes `"`. You should double-check your text editor / keyboard. How are you currently writing code?

Comment: @alterigel yes i copied this from the textbook mentioned above that's why. Otherwise i did fix it while implementing it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this `“`/`”` is not `"`, so the C++ compiler doesn't get that.

Second, a string literal is a `const char[]`, which *decays* into a `const char*`, so it won't call the `char[]` constructor.

The Fix:

```cpp
String(const char* s) //takes a string literal
{
    strcpy(str, s);
}
```

Be sure to replace your quotes with ASCII quotes (`"`).